# Function running multiple times jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Below is a function attached to the `keyup` event, this function works as it should on the first `keyup`, but on each subsequent `keyup` it runs the function multiple times. So for example, on first `keyup` event the function runs 1 time, on the 2nd `keyup` event the function runs 2 times, on the 3rd `keyup` it runs it 3 times and so on.

```
 $(document).on('pageinit','#address_page,#edit_address_page', function(){                                      
         $(".names").focus(function() {                                                                                        
         $(this).on('keyup', function() { 
         // Do Something
});
```

I have read other posts on this issue, but was unable to apply it to my scenario. Can someone please advise on this.

Answer (score 2):

You're re-binding the `keyup` event every time the element is focused.

If you want to bind like that, you should also have a `blur` event to unbind it. Really, though, you can probably safely just bind the `keyup` and not worry about the `focus`. That element will only actually trigger a `keyup` WHEN it is `focused`.

```
$(".names").keyup(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is every time the input is focused a new keyup handler is added so try(not sure about the jquery mobile syntax and need for `pageinit`)

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#address_page, #edit_address_page', function () {
    $(this).find('.names').on('keyup', function () {
        // Do Something
    });
});
```